# How do you hide a column in a datagrid using the .net compact framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a DataGrid that is using a DataReader as its datasource.  I want to hide the first column of the datagrid.  I am using the .net compact framework 3.5.  I can find examples for windows forms but the api is changed enough that they don't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the column style width to `0` or `-1`.

```
DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
ts.MappingName = "Order";

// Order date column style
DataGridColumnStyle cust_id = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
cust_id.MappingName = "cust_id";
cust_id.HeaderText = "ID";

//Hide Customer ID
cust_id.Width = -1;

ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(cust_id);

// Shipping name column style
DataGridColumnStyle cust_name = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
cust_name.MappingName = "cust_name";
cust_name.HeaderText = "Customer";
cust_name.Width = 500;
ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(cust_name);

GridView1.TableStyles.Add(ts);
```

Comment: It might worth mentioning the DataGridColumnStyle`.MappingName` must be unique. Resytling requires GridColumnStyles.Clear() before Add(), or locate & modify exisiting ColStyle with the right MappingName.

Answer (score 3):

In any event, before you
assign the datasource, hide the columns you do not want to show:

```
ds.Tables("dtRecords").Columns("ID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden

Datagrid1.datasource = ds.Tables("dtRecords")
```

Comment: This would work but as I mentioned I am using a DataReader and not a DataTable

Comment: @DaDa anyway to make this work with List<BusinessObj>? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem using DataGridTableStyle and GridColumnStyles as Henk says. But, I have, also, assigned the Width property, in the GridColumnStyle, to -1.

And, it works!!