# Hide column in datagrid (Framework 2.0)

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datatable, windows-ce

I'm building an app for Win CE 5.0 in VB.net framwork 2.0. I have a DataGrid (note: no DataGridView! :-)) with a DataTable as source.

In this case I want the last column to be hidden. I still want this value in this column if i call for it, but I want it invisible for the user. How can i do that..?

Edit: This is what i have

```
Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable("myTable")
' Filling my table ... '
MyDataGrid.DataSource = Table
```

I have tried this before setting the datasource, but no luck (i try with index 0 just to test)

```
Dim Table As DataTable = New DataTable("myTable")
' Filling my table ... '
Table.Columns(0).ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
MyDataGrid.DataSource = Table
```

But no column is hidden.

Comment: My first try. There is no Columns() on DataGrid...? The intellisense gives me only ColumnHeadersVisible (bool).

Comment: I do how ever have the .Columns() on the DataTable, but then i don't have the "visible" :) And it does not feel right to manipulate the datatable, it should be something i do on the DataGrid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you hide a column in a datagrid using the .net compact framework 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849330/how-do-you-hide-a-column-in-a-datagrid-using-the-net-compact-framework-3-5)